# Design pattern - database many to many

Tags: sql, database, many-to-many, junction-table

I have a question about many-tomany relationship. I know that we have to create a junction table. But let say we have this scenario:

one table for Customers
one table for Orders
one table for products

One order can have many products and one product might be in many orders. Therefore we create a junction table.
Could I just create a junction table between Customers and products and this junction would be a Order table to store the Orders?

Thanks

Comment: You would need an `OrderProducts` table. `Orders` would have `CustomerID`, and `OrderProducts` would have many `OrderID` and `ProductID` it would still need its own index because the many of the same `Product` might be on that `Order`

Comment: Alternatively, you could have `OrderProducts` use `OrderID` and `ProductID` as a composite primary key, and include a `Quantity` field.

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to create a junction table ala `CustomerProducts` because it wouldn't allow you to combine the various rows into individual `Orders`

Answer (score 2):

If you do that, how would you know which products a customer included on a specific order? And, how would you handle the customer ordering the same product on multiple orders?

So, no, you can't just create a Customer to Product junction table because that will not give you the information you ultimately need.

Comment: You are right. Do you recommend create a composite key in the OrderProduct table?

Comment: If yes. Is it a good practice, lets say, create the primary key of the order table, combining the foreign key(customerID) and the orderID. Then create a combined key in the OrderProduct from the foreign key of the order(customerID and orderID) + the productID. Therefore would be easier to query.

Comment: I avoid composite keys most times. The problem I've run into is too many columns in the composite key. In this example, if you do a composite key in OrderProduct, a key in OrderProductThing now contains three columns. Writing those queries gets painful as composite keys include more and more columns.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Are you running a particular report or query that gives you double ups? Or is this just a modelling exercise? Every Orders database I've seen has an Order Header table (with Customer) and an Order Detail Table (With Product and Order Header ID)

Comment: It is just a modelling exercise. If I do like you said how can I query to know all the products names that the user has bought. Isn't better have a composite foreign (customerID and OrderID) in the OrderProduct table, so it'd be much easier to query?

Comment: That violates third normal form (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) so I recommend it (it makes maintaining the data more difficult). Plus, with the way SQL works, it's pretty easy to join in a CustomerOrder table to relate a customer to products.